# Ghost : {{#each posts}} on all pages

Tags: node.js, ghost

How to use {{#each posts}} on another page that index.hbs in a [Ghost](https://ghost.org) theme ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `{{#get }}` helper on other pages as they don't already have a list of values. Here is the page talking about it in the theme docs. https://themes.ghost.org/docs/get

Comment: Thank you ! It's perfect :)

Comment: @Kazou you should accept JTWebMan's answer and upvote it if it was right. Makes SO a better place :)